# unable to use aggregate function on multiple queries in one query

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query... i am unable to use aggregate function - count on multiple tables at once.

```
$qu="SELECT distinct calls.c_number, count(type) as count1,SUM(charges * duration) as total,sum(duration) as duration1,billing_details.payment as pay,packages.(count)activation as act
 FROM calls
  INNER 
    JOIN packages
    ON calls.c_number=packages.c_number 
 WHERE

 calls.date>= DATE_FORMAT( $date, '%Y/%m/01' ) AND


calls.date< DATE_FORMAT( $date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01') group by c_number desc having SUM(charges * duration) > 0  ";
```

it gives me this error:

```
FUNCTION packages.count does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with PHP...

It's to do with your top line -

```
$qu="SELECT distinct calls.c_number, count(type) as count1,SUM(charges * duration) as total,sum(duration) as duration1,billing_details.payment as pay,packages.(count)activation as act
```

What do you expect "packages.(count)activation" to do? Do you mean `count(packages.activation)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
count(packages.activation)
```

instead of this

```
 packages.(count)activation
```

Comment: i have tried this but its giving me wrong output  ... m not getting the correct count